# Elementary, my dear …

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, chemistry

> ### My list for today
>
> - Iodine-Sulfur+Americium-Scandium:Phosphorus
> - Iodine-Titanium+Molybdenum+Thorium+Yttrium-Lithium:Helium
> - Praseodymium+Oxygen+Vanadium+Erbium+Boron+Sulfur-Lithium:Aluminum
> - Germanium+Neon+Silicon+Sulfur-Tin:Hydrogen#Carbon
> - Phosphorus+Sulfur-Cesium:Neon
>
> **______**
>
> Iodine-Potassium+Iodine-Sulfur:Oxygen
>   Iodine+Sulfur-Barium:Neon#Calcium
>   Praseodymium+Oxygen+Vanadium+Erbium+Boron+Sulfur-Neon:Nitrogen#Helium

James VI and I wanted me to tell you:
*Many words can have different meanings, but that's not usually true of the words in this list.

But here, these words **do** have different meanings, depending on how they're being used.*

**What is the meaning of all this?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The message says

> HAVE A HAPPY FATHER'S DAY / IN LOVING MEMORY

and it works as follows:

> everything up to the last "-" uses the elements' symbols to indicate a *book of the bible*; after that the element numbers indicate a *chapter and verse*; sometimes there is also a *word number*. (When there isn't we take the first word.)

And of course

> the note about "King James VI and I" (that's a Roman number 1, not a first-person-singular pronoun) indicates that we should use the so-called King James translation.

We get

> I Samuel 21:15 **Have** ...
>  I Timothy 3:2 **A** ...
>  Proverbs 3:13 **Happy** ...
>  Genesis 50:1 #6 ... **father's** ...
>  Psalm 55:10 **Day**
>  --
>  I Kings 16:8 **In** ...
>  Isaiah 56:10 #20 ... **loving** ...
>  Proverbs 10:7 #2 ... **memory**

And

> Rubio, if this implies what I guess it does then I am sorry for your loss. [I don't mean to imply that it must have been very recent.]

Credit where due: There were a couple of errors in the first version of this answer, which I have fixed after Rubio kindly pointed them out.

Discredit where due: I originally claimed that one element in the process was "sometimes slightly sketchy", but the sketchiness was in fact all in my head. Sorry, Rubio!

Comment: (Thanks - it’s been just a few years, so recent enough that it still twinges now and again. Such is life?)

Comment: Fixes fixed. Thanks! And yes, alas, such is life.